# Transitive Closure and First Order Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Why is it not possible to represent transitive closure in First Order Logic?

I am learning about translating from  Description logic to FOL. In description logic, it is possible to have transitive closure but i am wondering how it is possible in FOL. I found that  it is not possible with  FOL.  The reason I found is " as a consequence  of compactness theorem, it is not possible".  I couldn't understand its meaning.

Comment: Because you would need an infinite formula listing all the possible cases of transitivity of all possible variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context is as follows:

Given relation symbols $R, \overline R$, suppose there were a formula $\phi(R,\overline R)$ expressing that $\overline R$ is the transitive closure of $R$. Consider furthermore the constant symbols $c_1, c_2$ and construct the theory comprising $\phi(R,\overline R), c_1 \mathrel{\overline R} c_2$, and for each $n \in \Bbb N = \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$:
$$\neg (\exists x_1\ldots x_n : c_1 \mathrel R x_1 \mathrel R \cdots \mathrel R x_n \mathrel R c_2)$$
where I abused some notation for brevity's sake. This is manifestly inconsistent.

By the Compactness Theorem, a finite set of these is already inconsistent. It does not require a lot of thought, however, to see that any finite set is consistent.

Thus $\phi$ cannot exist.

Comment: why do you need negation? are you trying to check does it entail any given theory?

Comment: $\phi$ says that one of infinitely many possibilities has to be true. Subsequently I add the negation of all these possibilities to the theory under consideration, so that it becomes inconsistent. Here, theory is used in its model-theoretic sense: just a set of formulas whose models we want to study.